# What does this mean /16 after an IP address

Tags: linux, networking, ip-address, subnets

I came across an ip like this the other day `255.255.255.1/16`

I thought the `/16` referred to the number of subnetting addresses the IP could generate. However, I suspect I may be horribly wrong and felt that the Linux/Unix experts on this forum could assist.

Comment: this is the mask : number of IP address in the network (the mask) then you can determinate the number from the mask

Comment: @francoisP so what you are saying mate is that if my network ip is say 1.2.3.4/24 then the network of ip 1.2.3.4 has exactly 24 IP addresses??

Comment: that is the number of `1` bits in the subnet mask ... sane as 255.255.0.0

Comment: Note that nothing about this is specific to, or directly connected to, Linux.  Or Unix for that matter.  Hence https://superuser.com/q/196444/38062 and https://superuser.com/q/111593/38062 and https://superuser.com/q/922232/38062 and https://superuser.com/q/528775/38062 and https://superuser.com/q/1464492/38062 and …

Comment: Let's drop some names: [__CIDR__](https://www.google.com/search?q=CIDR%20notation)

Answer (score 18):

The value after the slash, i.e. the `24` in your example `192.168.1.0/24`, uses [CIDR notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) to
indicate the number of bits available for network addressing as distinct from host addressing. For IPv4 each IP address is 32 bits, and the network address for a `/24` network has 24 bits, so the host addressing for such a network would be 32 - 24 = 8 bits.

Let's look at this a bit more closely.

Take an example address `192.168.1.0/24`. This says that 24 bits of the 32 are for the network address. Each octet is 8 bits so it become trivially easy to see that this means that `192.168.1` is the network address, and the remainder is for the host. Eight bits gives 2<sup>8</sup> addresses, i.e. 256. The lowest (`0`) is unavailable and the highest (`255`) is reserved for local network broadcasts, so that leaves room for 254 host addresses, all beginning with `192.168.1`.

Now take another example address `192.168.0.0/16`. Here we have 16 bits of the 32 for network addressing, leaving 16 bits for the hosts on the network. We have 2<sup>16</sup> = 65536 host addresses but, as before, two are reserved (`192.168.0.0` and `192.168.255.255`) so you have 65534 available addresses for hosts on this network, all starting `192.168`.

This is all very easy; where it gets exciting is when the subnet field is not a multiple of eight. For example, you could have a network `192.168.1.128/26`. The same rules apply though; you have 26 bits for the network address and 6 bits for the hosts on that network. 2<sup>6</sup> is 64 and two are reserved so you can have 62 hosts on such a network. Using the `ipcalc` tool you can see that the valid IP addresses on this network would be `192.168.1.129` to `192.168.1.190`:

```
ipcalc 192.168.1.128/26
Address:   192.168.1.128        11000000.10101000.00000001.10 000000
Netmask:   255.255.255.192 = 26 11111111.11111111.11111111.11 000000
Wildcard:  0.0.0.63             00000000.00000000.00000000.00 111111
=>
Network:   192.168.1.128/26     11000000.10101000.00000001.10 000000
HostMin:   192.168.1.129        11000000.10101000.00000001.10 000001
HostMax:   192.168.1.190        11000000.10101000.00000001.10 111110
Broadcast: 192.168.1.191        11000000.10101000.00000001.10 111111
Hosts/Net: 62                    Class C, Private Internet
```

Answer (score 4):

An `/16` is usually used to indicate the number of bits that are fixed (would not change) in a range of addresses of a network. That is a simpler syntax to express the [CIDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing).

Having an IP number as 1.2.255.1/16 means that any address from 1.2.0.0 up to 1.2.255.255 is part of that address range or network.

However, an IP number that starts with 255, **similar** to the one you wrote 255.255.255.1/16 is usually used **only** for [netmask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork#Internet_Protocol_version_4) and means that the first 16 bits are fixed and the rest may change.

A mask of 255.255.0.0 and an a.b.c.d/16 have the exact same masking bits (or bits used).

An IP of 255.255.255.255 is [reserved by IANA for future use](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv4-address-space/ipv4-address-space.xhtml) and **also** called the *"limited broadcast" destination address* for the 0.0.0.0 network. Or, in layman terms [Broadcast Address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address).

The full explanation is a bit longer, but this is the gist of it.

Answer (score 0):

The diminish following the IP address is the abbreviation for the subnet mask. ... The quantity of ones in the subnet masks is equal to the range of the abbreviation. For example, the /16 subnet masks you asked about would have sixteen ones in a row, the relaxation of the numbers being zeros. 11111111.11111111. 00000000.00000000.